# Spring RestTemplate chaining

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

There is a method for downloading the file. As an argument, it takes an object that stores two fields: a direct `link` and a unique `id`. I need to download the file using one of these fields. Here's what `RestTemplate` queries look like:

```
private byte[] downloadByLink(String link) {
    return restTemplate.exchange(
            link,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            null,
            byte[].class
    ).getBody();
}

private byte[] downloadById(String id) {
    return restTemplate.exchange(
            getUniqueLink(id), // returns a link to download the file with the passed id
            HttpMethod.GET,
            null,
            byte[].class
    ).getBody();
}
```

I need to make a similar logic: if an object with these fields has both a direct `link` and an `id`, then I need to try to download the file from the `link`. If the `link` fails to download the file, then I need to try to download it via `id`. If it fails, then throw an exception. How can I do that?

Comment: Isn't the `id` just an alias for `link`, so even if you have both, the `link` is what matters? Or does `getUniqueLink()` return a different value than what `link` is?

Comment: @Kayaman yes, the direct link and the link by id are different. The `getUniqueLink` method simply wraps the `id` in a special link where you can download the file by `id`. Something like `'/speciallink?id=' + id`